# Fatal error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string() in magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7

Fatal error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string() in Magento 1.7.0.2  this error occurs when I am trying to set the site on the test server with PHP 5.6.

> error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string()
>   /home/myforeig/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line
>   510"

I have check phpinfo  SimpleXML and XML extensions are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with PHP 5.5 and earlier because Magento 1.7 does not support PHP 5.6.

Hope this can be helpful :)

Regards
Ketan

Comment: not work the same issue with 5.4 and 5.5.